# Getting records from student table whose enrolment_id is null

Tags: php, sql, database-design

`enrolment_id` is foreign key in `student` table and I want to get those students whose foreign key hasn't been set yet. Meaning `enrolment_id = NULL` (but this doesn't work in `WHERE` clause).

What to do?

Comment: `SOMETHING = NULL` is always FALSE (even `NULL=NULL` is `FALSE`). Just use `enrolment_id IS  NULL`

Comment: Can't compare something to NULL, NULL is technically speaking, not a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing `NULL` values, use the `IS NULL` predicate instead:

```
...
WHERE enrolment_ID IS NULL;
```

`= NULL` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM student AS s WHERE s.enrolment_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes...i have not refreshed my page :)